# Delete or Update if 3 object existed at the same time - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building LIKE, UNLIKE and CLAPPING function for my blog website. I have models like this:
**Model REACTION (Like, unlike and clapping)**

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    REACT_TYPES = (
        (LIKE, 'Like'),
        (CLAPPING, 'Clapping')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    react_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REACT_TYPES, default='LIKE')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

Serializers model REACTION
from models import Reaction

```
class ReactCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reaction
        fields = [
            'user',
            'react_type',
            'content_type',
            'object_id',
        ]
```

My REACT Viewset:

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
class ReactCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Reaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReactCreateUpdateSerializer
```

I assumed **there is a object with LIKE available created before**. I want to build a function can do these things:

- If user use again POST methods with 4 objects existed: `user, content_type, object_id, react_type=LIKE`. It becomes deleting object. (UNLIKE). Then if post one more, it becomes creating object again. (LIKE)
- If user use POST methods with 4 objects existed: `user, content_type, object_id, react_type=CLAPPING`. It becomes updating the available reactions in database with update 2 fields: react_type and timestamp, all other fields not changed.

*I think this is a problem for every one when he build API for website needs reaction. So Hope your enthusiastic help. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: No need to delete record, you can just update its `react_type= UNLIKE `  if  already LIKED by that user.

Comment: Can I update def in models.py or serializers.py? Is there an example @Satendra

Answer (score 1):

You just have to send `react_type` in request data, 
`object_id` will always be there if you create a *@detail_route* as *`pk`* also `user` object will be available in request if user is logged in as *`request.user`*

> Reaction object for any user will be created on first request made by that user.

No need to delete record, you have to update reaction object `react_type=UNLIKE` if already `LIKED` by user.

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # Data model on which user is reacting
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def react(self, request, pk=None):

        react_type = request.data['react_type']
        obj = self.get_object()

        # GenericForeignKey does not support get_or_create
        try:
            reaction_obj = Reaction.objects.get(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), object_id=obj.id, user=request.user)  
            reaction_obj.react_type = react_type
            reaction_obj.save()
        except Reaction.DoesNotExist:
            obj.reactions.create(user=request.user, react_type=react_type)

        return Response({'success': True})
```

Your Model on which user is reacting should have polymorphic connection

```
class Post(models.Model)
    # Other fields
    ...
    reactions = GenericRelation(Reaction, related_query_name='posts')
```

Register your viewset as

```
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostViewSet.as_view(), name='post-reaction')
# http://domian.com/api/v1/posts/1/react 
# method: POST
# data : {'react_type': 'UNLIKE'}
# content-type: 'application/json'
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not really got it. But I use CreateAPIView instead ModelViewSet in your code. and I have no reactions fields in Post. How can I fix your code?

Comment: You have to create a reactions field in your post model, I have given you example for viewset as you mentioned that you are using drf. can you add your view to question I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: I use ContentType to make connections with Post Model. I updated Viewsets. Hope your help!

Comment: CreateAPIView will not work in this case you have to use ModelViewSet as i explain in answer and update url accordingly.

Comment: Your code work successful but It continues to create obj instead of update the old one. I think have prolem in PostViewSet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159982/discussion-between-satendra-and-feed-git).